# Swift-function for finding missing Integers in an array of sequential Integers

Tags: algorithm, swift

**Task description:**

Implement a function, which receives an array of unsorted numbers from 1 to 100. In the array zero or more numbers might be missing. The function shall return an array containing the missing numbers.

**Provided Test-data with expected result:**

```
var arrTest = Array(1...100)
arrTest.remove(at: 25)
arrTest.remove(at: 20)
arrTest.remove(at: 6)

print(findMissingIn(numbers: arrTest))
```

With these test-data your function shall return [7, 21, 26] as missing numbers.

**My solution:**

```
func findMissingIn(numbers: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var missingNums = [Int]()
    
    for i in 1...100 {
        if numbers.contains(i) == false {
            missingNums.append(i)
        }
    }
    
    return missingNums
}
```

My function returns the expected result. So I guess it's formally correct.

**- Is there a better solution?**

**- What's your opinion about my naming and coding-style in general. Would you have done it differently. How? Why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the spirit of the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://www.swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), in particular

> Prefer method and function names that make use sites form grammatical English phrases.

I would call the method

```
func missingNumbers(in numbers: [Int]) -> [Int]
```

so that it is used as

```
print(missingNumbers(in: arrTest))
```

Comparing a boolean value with `true` or `false` is unnecessary, i.e.

```
if numbers.contains(i) == false { ... }
```

is (in my opinion) better written as

```
if !numbers.contains(i) { ... }
```

Instead of an explicit loop and a temporary array we can apply `filter` to a range:

```
func missingNumbers(in numbers: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return (1...100).filter { !numbers.contains($0) }
}
```

which is concise but still easy to read.

(The `return` keyword can be omitted if the function body consists of a single expression, that is a matter of personal taste.)

If *many* containment test are done against the same collection of values then it can be advantageous to convert the array to a Swift `Set` first because `Set.contains()` is a \$ O(1) \$ operation. It probably makes no performance difference for 100 values, but this is what it would look like:

```
func missingNumbers(in numbers: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let set = Set(numbers)
    return (1...100).filter { !set.contains($0) }
}
```

Comment: Searching for elements in a Set is indeed O(1) but the hashing adds a constant that may not be negligible in some situations https://twitter.com/iklilelyamani/status/1077298360632135680
. The Strategy Pattern could be used to choose the appropriate data structure based on the count of elements in `numbers`

Comment: @ielyamani: Can you share your benchmarking code?

Comment: Back then, I used [Attabench](https://swiftrocks.com/benchmarking-swift-code-properly-with-attabench)

Comment: For example, this minimalistic [solution](https://swiftfiddle.com/jxbqbtbdufgbrhtjpvohkdpuoi) gives me a 20X better time on my local machine. Optimizations can be turned on with `-O` in the settings of SwiftFiddle.